# One-sided identities in Banach algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, banach-algebras

What is an example of a Banach algebra with a left identity but with no right identities? Is there an example of an operator algebra with this property?

Comment: See also Theorem 1.8 here http://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.01213.pdf for an example of a Banach algebra where you can find simultaneosly ideals with/without certain bounded approximate identities. Apologies for self-promotion.

Comment: Dustan gave you a nice example below.  I'll add the trivial observation that this behavior can't occur in $*$-algebras.  If $e$ is a left identity, then $e^*$ is a right identity, and $e = ee^* = e^*$.  In particular, there aren't any $C^*$ algebras with this property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the two-dimensional subalgebra of $M_2(\mathbb C)$ spanned by the matrices $$A := \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} \text{ and } B := \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$ Then it is easy to verify that $A$ and $B$ both serve as left identities for this algebra. Obviously, being a subalgebra of a matrix algebra, this algebra can be given the structure of a Banach algebra and of an operator algebra.